SELinux - Domain transition failing
I've been trying to implement a custom policy that would enable a terminal from the context unconfined_u:unconfined_o:unconfined_t to execute specific system calls from an executable with the context default_u:object_o:default_t. I've created the following selinux policy and applied it with semodule -i:
module test2 1.0;
require {
        type default_t;
        type unconfined_t;
        class process transition;
        class memprotect mmap_zero;
        class process execheap;
}

#============= unconfined_t ==============
allow unconfined_t default_t:process transition;
type_transition unconfined_t default_t:process default_t;
role_transition unconfined_r {default_t unconfined_t} object_r;
allow default_t self:memprotect mmap_zero;
allow default_t self:process execheap;

I can invoke the executable directly and get the program's help file to appear with this policy. However, when this executable is either ran from within a script in the user's home directory (context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t) or copied directly into the terminal, SELinux blocks the system calls. audit2allow only recommends granting access for these two system calls to unconfined_t which would invalidate the reasoning behind the domain transition. Additionally, the audit log shows that both the source and target context are of unconfined_t, which doesn't line up with the script nor the executable being invoked.
I guess my main questions are

Why are these calls not getting switched from unconfined_t to default_t?
How can I guide SELinux into using this transition?

Many thanks for your assistance in this regard.
